# col() function behaves differently in PySpark when used with and without dataframe alias

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Example.
If I create a employee-manager dataframe using:

```py
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    data=[(1, "Robert", 2), (2, "Ria", 3), (3, "James", 5)],
    schema="empId int, empname string, manager_id int",
)
```

and then create a self join on manager id and employee_id by aliasing this table in two different names like:

```py
join_df = (
    df1.alias("emp1")
    .join(df1.alias("emp2"), col("emp1.manager_id") == col("emp2.empId"), "inner")
    .select(
        col("emp1.empId"),
        col("emp1.empname").alias("employee"),
        col("emp2.empname").alias("manager_name"),
        col("emp2.manager_id"),
    )
)
```

I need to use `col("emp1.manager_id") == col("emp2.empId")` as the join condition. Notice we are referring dataframe "emp1" with column "manager_id" inside column function. This statement works fine in this case.

But usually `col()` only takes in a column name and not the dataframe reference.

If I use this logic on dataframes where I am not doing an alias, it will throw an error:

> "emp1.manager_id" not found, do you mean "manager id"?~

**Issue:**

I want to find out, when it is normal to give dataframe reference inside `col()` function and when we should not give dataframe reference?

Comment: The error is normal. If you do not use alias, `emp1.manager_id` cannot exists as you did not define emp1.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing the dataframe inside the column expression like `col("emp1.manager_id")` (i.e. using `alias` on dataframes) is often not only best practice recommendation, but a requirement when we

- do self joins;
- join dataframes having columns with identical names.

If in such cases you don't use dataframe aliases and try to reference columns, you would get an *"AnalysisException: Reference 'col_name' is ambiguous..."*

Otherwise, you're safe not using this notation, as it may clutter your code too much without a good reason.

Comment: """Otherwise, you're safe not using this notation, as it may clutter your code too much without a good reason."""

 I am happy with the fact that col("emp1.manager_id") is required when self join is used. However, I am not happy with the fact that in cases where I am using an inner join. Spark will throw an error when I use col("emp1.manager_id"). It will expect me to say col("manager_id"). I want spark to behave consistently. Atleast should not throw errors when I mention dataframe inside col(), as it does allow it when using self joins.

Comment: If you use `alias` on both dataframes which take part in the `inner join` too. You can do it anywhere actually. When you add `alias`, you can use `col(emp1.manager_id)`. This is a simple one-line example of inner join where you can see such notation in action: `spark.range(3).alias('a').join(spark.range(5).alias('b'), F.col('a.id') == F.col('b.id'))`

Comment: Yes, thanks for the example and example. Very helpful. This shows that col("df_aliased.colA") is required when alias is used. My question stays the same. If we dont use alias, why cant we use F.col("original_df_name.colA")

Comment: If you don't use alias, instead of `F.col("original_df_name.colA")` you can use `original_df_name.colA` or `original_df_name["colA"]`

Comment: my question has always been about col() function.  I am aware of other ways of selecting columns. I need to understand why col("df.colA") breaks without alias. It is not mentioned in the documentation or elsewhere.